# Using ajax to dynamically load modal details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I currently have a foreach in one of my blades. I want to create a button on each entry that will prompt a modal to show with some further details. I have the modal working correctly using many different methods (I had to try multiple due to the ensuing problem) but couldn't get a small feature I wanted to work.

```
// this is inside the foreach. isStaff is a custom attribute.
@if(auth::check() && auth::user()->isstaff)
    <span style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;" class="quickview btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" value="{{ $loop->index }}"> // loop used to get index of foreach
     <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </span>
@endif
```

I basically want to have two arrows on the top of the modal (pictured) that would either go to the previous or next entry in the foreach.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XvdT.png) (sorry can't embed yet)

I'm wondering how i can handle this logic? at first, I passed in the id through my controller for the specified entry the incremented and decremented it, though i cannot pass the collection through.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.quickview').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modal').find(".modal-body").load("admin/preview/" + $(this).attr('value'));

        });
});
```

Basically, is there a way to pass either the collection through, or dynamically change the ids in the modal then showing it? I had tried a `var collection = "<?php json_encode($collection); ?>";` but i could no longer use relationships.
I had also tried an ajax request where I passed in the collection but a similar problem of not having relationships occurred.

I had thought about simply making the new URLs ex. admin/preview/n +1 and n - 1, though realistically I still need the collection in order to do `$collection[n]` to display

Sorry for the noob-ish question, thank you for reading and for any help in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can't use the relations because they are not loaded yet. Have you tried, loading them via `with()`?

Comment: @shaedrich using json_encode makes them an object instead of an eloquent object, im not sure if with() could resolve that problem since im using the index ID vs eloquent objcect ID

Comment: The relations are serialized if they are loaded according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays)